# python seleniumwire and debugging mode result doesn't work

Tags: python, debugging, mode, seleniumwire

I would like to use the python seleniumwire with the debugging mode

but it doesn't come out theh result.

If I use no debugger mode, the result is come out

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver  # Import from seleniumwire
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time

# Set up Chrome options with debugger address
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('debuggerAddress', '127.0.0.1:9225')

# Create a new instance of the Chrome driver with debugger mode enabled
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

# Go to the Google home page
driver.get('https://www.google.com')
time.sleep(3)


# Access requests via the 'requests' attribute
for request in driver.requests:
    if request.response:
        print(
            request.url,
            request.response.status_code,
            request.response.headers['Content-Type']
        )
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZrDE.png)

use no debugger mode
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vma6e.png)

I tried so many, please help me .

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.